# Pandas: DataFrame op DataFrame Results in NaNs

Tags: pandas, dataframe, alignment, operators, union

Why do simple DataFrame op DataFrame operations result in a union'ed DataFrame? Pandas documentation mentions unionizing because of alignment issues. I don't see any alignment issues with df1 and df2. Aren't alignment issues about different shapes, different dtypes, or different indexes?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[3,4]],columns=list('AB'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[5,6],[7,8]],columns=list('CD'))

>> df1*df2

    A   B   C   D
0   NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Another source of alignment issues is non-matching column names. Here, alignment requires identical column names. Either make the column names the same or use `.values`. Using `.values` on just the right-hand DataFrame will retain the DataFrame type.

```
>> df1*df2.values

    A   B
0   5   12
1   21  32
```